# 960grid and columns having 960px width together?

Tags: css

Okay, so this thing bugs me all day long. I want to use 960gs with my latest project, but I want to have two columns, one `.grid_15 alpha omega` and the other one `.grid_8 alpha omega prefix_1`. When I do this, columns have 590px and 350px. How to make them meet 960px?

Answer (score 0):

Each grid has 10 pixels of margin on each side (so you'll get 20px between each grid).

590 + 350 = 940 + 20 = 960.

So it's working the way it's intended with the full 960 pixels taken up by however many grids you use.